# Error message : [This stream is not active and must be resumed using the \'forceActive\' parameter. (STREAM_INACTIVE)]

Tags: graphql, pandora

I get the above error message while running replay query. Although in the documentation I could only find this:

```
“interactions” will contain “FORCE_ACTIVE” (this can be used by clients to detect the inactive stream and stop playback, instead of having to look for specific types).
```

In my understanding, we can just observe the value of `"FORCE_ACTIVE"` parameter to stop playback. While in the error message, I am being told to resume the stream by using `"FORCE_ACTIVE"`. I couldn't find out through the documentation about sending the `"FORCE_ACTIVE"` parameter from my end. Please help me understand the proper course of action if I get the above error message. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the question. We're looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you should display a message saying "Someone else is listening to your Pandora account. Only one person can listen at a time. Please try again later." We are working on adding a mechanism which would allow users to decide if they want to "take over control" but it's not ready yet. For reference, this is what shows up in the Pandora app when this situation arises:

[image]

The option to "Let me listen" is what we're adding. For now, you just have to default to "Let them listen".